# Copying the row of table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-redux, react-hooks

Hi I have a reqirement in `react`. I need to copy the `row of table in UI`. means once user `clicks` on the highlighted icon in `yellow` in below image. the same `row` should be `duplicated` .

Could you guide me , how can I approach for the same?

[image]

so the below row should appear twice.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So far, what you've tried? Can you show us some code, that you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the object that represents the row then just push the same into the array that consists of all this rows

```
array.push(clickedrow);
```

And let this array be a state so when you change it will rerender and you can see the updated list on UI.

Comment: We dont need to copy all the rows but only row which user clicls

Comment: push adds single row that you clicked to an existing array that represents the list. if this is not expected, can you explain what are you expecting ?